# When does $c$ divide $a^p+b^p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given coprime positive integers $a<b<c$ and $p$ an odd prime, when does $c | a^p+b^p$?

It seems to be when $c\equiv 1\pmod p$ or $c = (pk+1)(a+b)$. Is there a simple way to prove this?

Comment: Does $(13)$ divide $(2^3 + 3^3)$?  Alternatively, routine to show that when $n$ is an odd positive integer, $(x+y)$ divides $(x^n + y^n).$  The way that your query currently reads, you are not requiring that $c$ divides $(a+b)$.

Comment: Hint: ${(a+b)^p \equiv a^p + b^p(mod p)}$   now ${(a+b)^p= a+b (mod p)}$

Comment: @SSA how do I use the mod p information to determine $a^p+b^p \equiv 0 \pmod c$?

Comment: I posted a new question that is a more direct/useful version of this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255443/when-does-q-divide-xp-yp-x-y)