# When does $q$ divide $(x^p-y^p)/(x-y)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given odd prime $p$ and coprime integers $x$ and $y$, is there a simple proof (or counterexample) of the following:

Excluding the trivial case $p = q$, $(x^p-y^p)/(x-y)\equiv 0\pmod q \implies q\equiv 1\pmod p$.

For example, $q\mid x^2+x y + y^2 \implies q\equiv 1\pmod 3$. So, unlike the sum of two squares theorem, the prime factorization of $x^2+x y + y^2$ can only contain primes of the form $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

I believe any proof will also apply to $(x^p+y^p)/(x+y)$.

Comment: Looks like [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771781/if-p-and-q-are-primes-such-that-q-mid-fracxp-1x-1-then-prove-that) is useful, where $y=1$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime number, and $x$ and $y$ two coprime integers.
Let $q$ be a prime number distinct from $p$ such that $q$ divides $\frac{x^p-y^p}{x-y}$. Suppose that $q$ ​divides $x-y$. Then $x\equiv y\pmod{q}$ and so
$$\frac{x^p-y^p}{x-y}=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}x^iy^{p-1-i}\equiv py^{p-1}\pmod{q},$$
and so $q$ divides $y$ because $q\neq p$. It follows that $q$ also divides $x$, and so $q$ divides $\gcd(x,y)=1$, a contradiction. This shows that $q$ does not divide $x-y$, and so  $x\not\equiv y\pmod{q}$ and
$$x^p\equiv y^p\pmod{q},$$
because $q$ divides $\tfrac{x^p-y^p}{x-y}$. This shows that the group homomorphism
$$(\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{\times}\ \longrightarrow\ (\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{\times}:\ n\ \longmapsto\ n^p,$$
is not injective, which implies that $(\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ contains elements of order $p$, and so $p\mid(q-1)$, or equivalently
$$q\equiv1\pmod{p}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer! I'm mostly unfamiliar with group theory. I think you're referring to the multiplicative group of integers modulo $q$. Can you briefly comment on what the group homomorphism notation indicates? or why the group has to contain elements of order $p$.

Comment: That is indeed the group I am referring to. It is a cyclic group of order $q-1$. It is a matter of routine verification to check that the map I give is indeed a group homomorphism. Because it is not injective there exists some $k\in(\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ such that $k^p\equiv1\pmod{q}$. This means $(\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ has a subgroup of order $p$, and hence that $p$ divides $q-1$. But all this of course presupposes some basic group theory, which I will not go into here.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?